# Show and lighting options do not work together

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying the example from [this demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/OverlappingLightColors/), but it is not working properly.

```
plane = ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, -2}, {u, -7, 7}, {v, -7, 7}, 
    PlotPoints -> 200, 
    MaxRecursion -> 2, 
    Mesh -> None, 
    Axes -> False, 
    Boxed -> False];

Manipulate[
  Show[plane,
    Lighting -> {
     {"Spot", RGBColor[1, 0, 0], {{0, r, 5}, {0, r, 0}}, Pi/8},
     {"Spot", RGBColor[0, 1, 0], {{-r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], 5}, {-r Sin[θ], r Cos[θ], 0}}, Pi/8},
     {"Spot", RGBColor[0, 0, 1], {{r Sin[ϕ], r Cos[ϕ], 5}, {r Sin[ϕ], r Cos[ϕ], 0}}, Pi/8}
    }, 
    PlotRange -> {(3 + r) {-1, 1}, (3 + r) {-1, 1}, Automatic},
    ImageSize -> {350, 320}],

 {{r, 2, "spacing"}, 0, 3.5},
 {{θ, 2 π/3, "green angle"}, π, 0},
 {{ϕ, 2 π/3, "blue angle"}, π, 0},
 "XYZ" -> {{RGB, {1, 1, 1}}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

It is not drawing any circles, only the plane.

Could you please suggest what is not right with my code?

Note 1: I am using 10.4 version of Mathematica, in 8.0 code works.

Comment: Yulia, you are missing a comma before the `"XYZ" -> ...`: if that's missing in your notebook as well, try fixing that and re-evaluating the code.

Comment: Originally, it was there. I have added it.

Comment: Question has been updated, it is not working in Mathematica 10.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works with Mathematica 10.4.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, -2}, {u, -7, 7}, {v, -7, 7}, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2, Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, 
  Boxed -> False,
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Specularity[10]}, 
  Lighting -> 
    {{"Spot", RGBColor[RGB[[1]], 0, 0], {{0, r, 5}, {0, r, 0}}, Pi/8}, 
    {"Spot", RGBColor[0, RGB[[2]], 0], {{-r Sin[theta], r Cos[theta], 5}, {-r Sin[theta], 
       r Cos[theta], 0}}, Pi/8}, 
    {"Spot", RGBColor[0, 0, RGB[[3]]], {{r Sin[phi], r Cos[phi], 5}, {r Sin[phi], 
       r Cos[phi], 0}}, Pi/8}}],
 {{r, 2, "spacing"}, 0, 3.5},
 {{theta, 2 Pi/3, "green angle"}, Pi, 0},
 {{phi, 2 Pi/3, "blue angle"}, Pi, 0},
 {{RGB, {1, 1, 1}}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

[image]